# Headless automation with Nodejs Selenium Webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I am working with an automation tool which has to be deployed inside an ubuntu server, my wonder is if is possible to use chrome in a silent way with Selenium Webdriver.

I've tried the following code so far, but it keeps opening the browser (I'm doing the tests in a Windows 10):

```
    var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        chrome    = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
        By        = webdriver.By,
        until     = webdriver.until,
        options   = new chrome.Options();
        options.addArguments('--headless');
    var path = require('chromedriver').path;
    var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
        chrome.setDefaultService(service);
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities()).build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');
```

Note that the addArguments('--headless') is the parameter that should make the navigation silent, but apparently it's not working or I am missing something I am not aware of.

If there is something I am missing, please tell me because I don't know if what I want to do is possible, as It is the frist time I work with this kind of technology.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? `--headless` works starting with version 59, version 60 on Windows.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Updated answer circa FEB-2018.

Referencing the [Selenium Webdriver NodeJS Examples (commit `5bf50c4`)](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/5bf50c43189ffac6ed08c3ca726b9db0f453a970/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/example/headless.js)

```
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

const screen = {
  width: 640,
  height: 480
};

let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments('--headless').windowSize(screen))
    .setFirefoxOptions(new firefox.Options().addArguments('--headless').windowSize(screen))
    .build();
```

Headless Chrome available since [major version 59.0](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) APR-2017

Headless Firefox available since [major version 56.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4591) SEP-2017

Comment: Thank you, that helped. You could just fix the screen object: {width:640,height:480}

Answer (score 13):

Try this one:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    chrome    = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
    By        = webdriver.By,
    until     = webdriver.until,
    options   = new chrome.Options();
    options.addArguments('headless'); // note: without dashes
    options.addArguments('disable-gpu')
var path = require('chromedriver').path;
var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
    chrome.setDefaultService(service);
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()) 
    .setChromeOptions(options)                         // note this
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');
```

Comment: What do By and Until do?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately the *headless()* method does not exist any more in Webdriver JS.

Use

```
const seleniumWebdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome')
            .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments('--headless'))
            .build();
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, for now we stopped using selenium webdriver and moved to puppeteer, a much more reliable solution for our scenario.

Comment: @avilac I completed the project in `selenium-webdriver` and now i found `puppeteer` was also a better solution oO. I will give it a shot in the next project,

Answer (score 2):

To start Chrome in headless mode, simply call `Options.headless()`. Starting in headless mode currently also disables GPU acceleration. This is the code:

```
  var seleniumWebdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
  var chrome    = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

  var options   = new chrome.Options().headless();

  var driver = new seleniumWebdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();
```

**Note:** For security, Chrome disables downloads by default when in headless mode. You may call `setDownloadPath` to re-enable downloads.