# How to hide browser window with Selenium in Node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium, e2e-testing

I am currently working on a Node.js project in which I use Selenium. Is there any way to hide the Chrome window after it launched without closing it, etc?

Comment: If you don't wanna see the Chrome browser, go for a headless option. or provide more information what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headless automation with Nodejs Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197253/headless-automation-with-nodejs-selenium-webdriver)